# "Reach" of variable in swift

Tags: swift

I'm writing a MacOS document-based app. For some reason, I have to write the same definition in every function of my ViewController.

```
let document = self.view.window?.windowController?.document as! Document
```

If I write it at the head of the ViewController class, I get an error that the view is undefined.

If I don't include this line in each function, then it complains that document is undefined.

I presume there must be a better way of doing this? An explanation of why it doesn't work and why other solutions do work would be super.

Comment: This is a very good question and  I would like down-votes to be removed.I'm flagging this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare this as a computed property:

```
var document: Document? {
    return self.view.window?.windowController?.document as? Document
}
```

Put this outside any functions, but inside the view controller class, so that it can be accessed anywhere in your view controller class.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Could you explain why that works but my line doesn't?

Comment: @benwiggy In a computed property, `self.view.window?.windowController?.document as! Document` will be evaluated every time you access `document`, instead of just once. If you just do `let document = ...`, then it will only be run once, when the view is not initialised.

Comment: ... So presumably it isn't actually evaluated when first parsed, so it doesn't flag the same error?

Comment: @Sweeper It might be better, from a performance perspective, to use a `lazy var` as a computed property is calculated on every access while a `lazy var` is calculated on first access

Comment: @Malik But wouldn't that flag the same error as my version?

Comment: @Malik I don't really like the idea of unnecessarily variable properties. If performance really was a problem, then I would use a lazy var. But now, I wouldn't worry too much _now_.

Comment: @molbdnilo OK, In other words, it's a function that doesn't get called until needed. Thanks.

Comment: @Sweeper The app is crashing when all documents are closed, and Xcode points to your computer property as the cause.

Comment: @benwiggy you probably shouldn’t use `as!`. Make the property an optional type and use `as?` instead. And unwrap the optional appropriately.

Comment: I've tried `return ((self.view.window?.windowController?.document as? Document)!)` but it's still flagging a Bad Instruction.

Comment: @benwiggy you are still force unwrapping the optional. Don’t. There are plenty of tutorials online about how to unwrap optionals safely. Your code should not contain any `!`. The type of the property should be `Document?` instead.

Comment: Sorry.  Adding ! to every document afterwards fixes it. I really don't understand optionals and wrapping, and I've looked at loads of documentation. "If in doubt, add more punctuation." ;-)

Comment: @benwiggy I don’t know why that worked (because it shouldn’t). Unfortunately, understanding how to use optionals is very important. You must understand that to write good swift code.

Comment: @Sweeper Many thanks for your patience. I think I'm aiming for functional, rather than good code.